# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick when trying to migrate to another page

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a notes app and every time I click on the create new note button my app crashes. Below I will attach my MainActivity and logcat! Everything was done according to the video tutorial however I am the only one who has this error. The video I'm using is about 3 years old, so I thought maybe something has changed. . . .

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.simnotereborn

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.example.simnotereborn.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.simnotereborn.databinding.EditActivityBinding
import com.example.simnotereborn.db.MyDbManager
import android.content.Intent

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val myDbManager = MyDbManager(this)

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

    }

    fun onClickNew(view: View) {

        val i = Intent(this, EditActivityBinding::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        myDbManager.closeDb()
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CBF1FFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoElements"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="No Elements"
        android:textColor="#A5C2CA"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_button"
        android:onClick="onClickNew"
        app:backgroundTint="#A8D9FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

edit_activity.xml (This is where i'm trying to migrate):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CBF1FFFF"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title of Note"
        android:hint="Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Content of Note"
        android:hint="Content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTitle"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Save button"
        app:backgroundTint="#A8D9FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.simnotereborn, PID: 10657
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
> android:onClick
> at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6474)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6469)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636) 
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
> explicit activity class
> {com.example.simnotereborn/com.example.simnotereborn.databinding.EditActivityBinding};
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does
> your intent not match its declared ?
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2236)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1878)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5589)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5547)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6045)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6012)
> at
> com.example.simnotereborn.MainActivity.onClickNew(MainActivity.kt:27)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6469) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636) 
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

So judging by Logcat it's seems like I'm missing something in Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SimNoteReborn"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.simnotereborn/com.example.simnotereborn.databinding.EditActivityBinding}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?

But I still don't fully understand exactly how to fix what he's talking about.

Comment: You need to include the rest of the stack trace

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused about what exactly I need to do. This is my first Kotlin project in Android Studio. . .

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace. If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Updated Logcat and included the rest of the stack trace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls:

```
val i = Intent(this, EditActivityBinding::class.java)
startActivity(i)
```

But your activity is not the `EditActivityBinding` class - it is just `EditActivity`.

So change your code to actually use your activity's class:

```
val i = Intent(this, EditActivity::class.java)
startActivity(i)
```

Comment: Oh. . . thank you. I don't know how I could have missed that. I feel stupid now. Thanks again, thank you so much!

Comment: The important thing to look at is always the "Caused by" section of the stack trace, which pointed out that it was looking for `EditActvitiyBinding`: `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.simnotereborn/com.example.simnotereborn.databinding.EditActivityBinding};`

Comment: Ah now I see. Thank you for advice!